# @MessageMapping does not work with Spring Security and MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket

I have an application that uses Spring MVC and Security.And I try to add Websockets to it. I already have successful connection but, when i try to send message to backend - nothing happends. In debug mode method annotated with  @MessageMapping does not reach at all! And I don know why. I have already tried a lot of Google solutions, so for now all configurations are next:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    public WebSocketConfig() {
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello1").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Also I have added security config for websockets

```
@Configuration
public class SecuritySocketConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }

    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.simpDestMatchers("/hello1").authenticated().simpDestMatchers("/app/hello1").authenticated();//permitAll();

    }
}
```

Controller class

```
@Controller
public class WebsocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello1")
    public void send(Message message) {
        String name = message.getName();

    }
}
```

socket.js, that is importing to JSP file

```
;(function () {

    //init
    $(function () {
        $("#control_mode").change(app.page.controlCheck);
        connect();
    });
    var stompClient = null;


    function connect() {
        var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/hello1");
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        console.log('attempt to connect: ' +stompClient!=null);
        console.log('session id: '+ "${pageContext.session.id}");

        stompClient.connect('', '', function(frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings/', function(result) {
                getResult(result);
            });

        });
    }

    function getResult(result) {
       var isControlable= JSON.parse(greeting.body).isControlable;
        if (isControlable) {
            alert('Control was already gained')
        } else {
            $("#control_mode").prop("checked", true);
        }
    }

    app.page.controlCheck = function () {
        stompClient.send('/app/hello1', {}, JSON.stringify({'name' : "alastor" }));
        if (this.checked) {
            $("#control_mode").prop("checked", !this.checked);
        } else {
            alert('was click for release control');
        }
    };

    function disconnect() {
        stompClient.disconnect();
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }
})();
```

spring-security.xml (further is importing to main spring.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/webjars/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/rest/**" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/favicon.ico" security="none"/>

    <http security="none" pattern="/pathWhereCSRFWillBeIgnored/**"/>
    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/ajax/welcome/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/ajax/**" access="permitAll"/>  <!--todo for testing-->

        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="@validateService.isValid(request)"/>
        <form-login login-page="/welcome"
                    authentication-failure-url="/welcome?error=true"
                    login-processing-url="/spring_security_check"
                    authentication-success-handler-ref="directLinkHandler"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/welcome"/>
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean class="com.promptlink.stbtp.webapi.listener.AuthenticationEventListener"/>

    <beans:bean class="com.promptlink.stbtp.service.security.util.PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

browser log:

```
Opening Web Socket... stomp.js:134:99
Web Socket Opened... stomp.js:134:99
>>> CONNECT
login:
passcode:
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

 stomp.js:134:99
<<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0
user-name:qwe

 stomp.js:134:99
connected to server undefined stomp.js:134:99
Connected: CONNECTED
user-name:qwe
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.1

 socket.js:18:13
>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/topic/greetings/

 stomp.js:134:99
>>> SEND
destination:/app/hello1
content-length:18

{"name":"alastor"}
```

Do somebody know what am I doing wrong?

**EDITION 1**
By the way, when I use this configs in simple project, without Spring-Security everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

So, i found the solution! The mistake was very simple. My `WebSocketConfig` was initialized by `IoC` context, not `MVC`. I moved it to package that was scanned by MVC context and all started work perfectly! If somebody has same situation be sure, that you web socket config class is initializing by MVC context.

Comment: Hi, i have the problem same with you, what do you mean "WebSocketConfig was initialized by IoC context, not MVC"?

Comment: This was exactly my problem, as well. In my test case configuration, my `WebSocketConfig` was not being picked up by the component scanning (added the `@ComponentScan` annotation to my test configuration and it worked).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.

I had to move my class that had @EnableWebMvc from getRootConfigClasses() to getServletConfigClasses() in my initialiser that extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.

```
public class MyAppInitiser extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
       return new Class[] { TaskSchedulerConfig.class, 
               AsyncConfig.class , WebSecurityConfig.class };
   }
   /* WebMvcConfig contains @EnableWebMvc */
   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] {WebSocketConfig.class ,  WebMvcConfig.class};
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }

}
```